# levels() is not accepting negative values. Any workaround?

Tags: r

Symboling is the insurance risk rating of cars.

```
str(carprice$symboling)
```

$ symboling       : Factor w/ 6 levels "-2","-1","0",..: 6 6 4 5 5 5 4 4 4 3 ...

```
levels(carprice$symboling)[-2:-1] <- "safe"
levels(carprice$symboling)[0:1] <- "mild risky"
levels(carprice$symboling)[2:3] <- "risky"

str(carprice$symboling)
```

$ symboling       : Factor w/ 2 levels "mild risky","risky": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...

Why are the negative levels not being expected?

Comment: note the quotes around `"-2"` in the output -- the `levels` are a `character` vector, not an index

Answer (score 2):

The indexing in `R` starts from 1.  It denotes the position of the value in the `vector`.  It can be column index or row index in data.frame, matrix.  Here, we are trying to assign the `levels` of the 'symboling' column to a particular value based on the position of the already existing levels.  Assuming that the levels are in the order of -2:3, the first two levels will be assigned to 'safe', then the next 2 to 'mild risky' and the last 2 with 'risky'

```
levels(carprice$symboling)[1:2] <- "safe"
levels(carprice$symboling)[3:4] <- "mild risky"
levels(carprice$symboling)[5:6] <- "risky"
```

---

This can be done in a single step too

```
levels(carprice$symboling) <- setNames(rep(c('safe', 'mild risky', 'risky'), each = 2),
              -2:3)[levels(carprice$symboling)]
```

As a reproducible example

```
set.seed(24)
v1 <- factor(sample(-2:3, 20, replace = TRUE))
levels(v1) <-  setNames(rep(c('safe', 'mild risky', 'risky'), each = 2), -2:3)[levels(v1)]
```